# Не срабатывает ajax success на мобильных устройствах для аудиофайлов

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, flask, jquery-mobile

Есть ajax запрос к скрипту на python, который говорит ему, какой аудиофайл обрабатывать

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/",
    data: {file: file.name},
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
      alert("after triggerFileProcessingOnServer");
      return;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert(error);
      return;
    }
  });
```

Обработка со стороны python выполняется хорошо, он возвращает результат (отслеживаю по консоли). Однако после этого не срабатывает ни ajax success, ни ajax error (ни один из alert'ов не отображается). Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

### ДОПОЛНЕНО:

Это не срабатывает только для больших файлов. Т.е., если ajax велит python обрабатывать маленький аудиофайл, то всё нормально. А если аудиофайл превышает 20 секунд, то ajax тормозит и не принимает ответ. Со стороны сервера обработка корректная (отслеживаю по консоли сервера).

Comment: А другие сайты где есть запросы на ajax нормально работают с этим браузером/телефоном?

Comment: @AndrewGrow даже в пределах этого сайта другие ajax срабатывают нормальною только здесь, почему-то, такая проблема возникает

Comment: Может надо полный урл? Просто код выглядит очень простым, непонятно чему там ломаться.

Comment: @AndrewGrow аналогичный код работает на компьютере и для небольших аудиофайлов. а вот на больших ломается - запрос отправляется, а вот ответ от сервера не обрабатывается

Answer (score 0):

Возможно на вашем мобильном устройстве не работает `alert`. 

На моем работает, я проверял.

В любом случае для вывода дебага на мобильных устройствах можете воспользоваться такой [маленькой библиотекой](https://github.com/gorbiz/mobile-console.log). Суть ее очень проста - перезаписать функцию `console.log`, чтобы она выводила всплывающее окно на мобильных устройствах, а на десктопных устройствах оставалась неизменной.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: { file: 'name' },
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log('after triggerFileProcessingOnServer');
      return;
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/gorbiz/mobile-console.log/master/console.js"></script>
```

Comment: alert поддерживается, т.к. в других местах он срабатывает. библиотеку попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот сто процентов рабочий код. Возможно, поможет найти проблему.

```
$('#welcome').find('a').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    getAjaxContent(href);
});

function getAjaxContent(href) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_content",
        type: "get",
        data: {jsdata: href},
        success: function(response) {
        $("#body_content").html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            // We may to do something to handle error
        },
        timeout : 1000 //timeout of the ajax call
    });
}
```

Comment: проблема моего кода - именно в том, что он не работает для больших файлов. т.е., сервер ответ отправляет по запросу, но ajax почему-то не может его обработать. т.е., для мобильных устройств этот код работает на небольших файлах, а для компьютерной версии этот код срабатывает без ограничений